# Insert statement with where in sql in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I wonder why the below stored procedure is not working.It gives error `invalid syntax near WHERE`.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE salary

    @salary int = 0,
    @id int =0

AS
 SET NOCOUNT ON 

BEGIN
  begin
    insert into account (Salary) values (@salary) where staffId = @id;
  end
END
```

Comment: What does the table structure look like, i.e. I assume staffId is a field in account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there's no "where" on insert syntax. 
example :

```
insert into account (staffid, salary) values (@id, @salary);
```

or you could use update syntax to update the data.

```
update account set salary = @salary where staffid = @id;
```